# Proof of binomial series in the case N is a real number

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

Could you please tell me how to prove the result below in the case that $n$ is not necessarily an integer ? (i.e. $n$ can be any real number so that $\binom{n+i}{i}$ is well defined). I just can't wrap my head up to the point of the manipulation of the combination of real numbers.

$$ 
{
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i\binom{n+i}{i}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}
}
$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Read this article I wrote](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123) and you can then try to derive taylor series of function on RHS

Comment: @Buraian that is a very well written and motivated introduction to Taylor series

Comment: I have written blog posts which deal with binomial series. [This post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part1.html?m=0) uses an approach based on Taylor series and [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html?m=0) uses multiplication of series.

Comment: Thank you, the nice comments are everything to me @FShrike

Answer (score 1):

We recall the definition of binomial coefficients below valid for real (even complex) $\alpha$:
\begin{align*}
\binom{\alpha}{n}:=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}\qquad\qquad \alpha\in\mathbb{C}, n\in\mathbb{N}_0
\end{align*}
Using this definition we can show the validity of the binomial identity
\begin{align*}
\binom{-\alpha}{n}=\binom{\alpha+n-1}{n}(-1)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{n+i}{i}x^i}
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{-n-1}{i}(-1)^ix^i\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{-(n+1)}{i}(-x)^i\tag{2.2}\\
> &=(1-x)^{-(n+1)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we apply the binomial identity (1).
- In (2.2) we use a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.